# Extension of $H_0^1$ functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega_0\subseteq \Omega_1$, with $\Omega_0,\Omega_1$ bounded and open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let us suppose that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $\text{supp} f \subseteq \Omega_0$. Consider the unique solutions $u_0\in H_0^1(\Omega_0),u_1\in H_0^1(\Omega_1)$ of the following variational problems $$\int_{\Omega_0} \nabla u_0\cdot \nabla \varphi=\int_{\Omega_0} f \varphi \qquad \forall\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega_0)$$
and
$$\int_{\Omega_1} \nabla u_1\cdot \nabla \varphi=\int_{\Omega_1} f \varphi \qquad \forall\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega_1)$$
I was wondering if the following statement is true: The function $u_1$ is the extension by zero of $u_0$ to $\Omega_1$.

Comment: Note that $\int_{\Omega_1} \nabla (u_0-u_1) \cdot \nabla \phi = 0$ (where we consider $u_0$ to be extended by $0$ on $\Omega_1$ to be well-defined).  As this holds for all $\phi \in H^1_0(\Omega_1)$, it follows that $u_0$ and $u_1$ differ only by a constant, which must be $0$ by the boundary conditions.

Comment: You are right. I am in a period that working too much on a problem I start to have doubt on simple proofs. If you answer I accept the answer.

Comment: I've certainly been there too.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$
\int_{\Omega_1} \nabla (\tilde{u}_0−u_1)\cdot \nabla \varphi=0,
$$
where $\tilde{u}_0$ is the extension of $u_0$ by $0$ on $\Omega_1\setminus \Omega_0$. As this holds for all $\varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega_1)$, it follows that $\tilde{u}_0$ and $u_1$ differ only by a constant, which must be $0$ by the boundary conditions.

Comment: This is wrong. The test functions for $u_0$ must be compactly supported in $\Omega_0$, so you cannot conclude that your identity holds for all $\phi \in H^1_0(\Omega_1)$. The best you can say is that $u_0$ and $u_1$ differ on $\Omega_0$ by a harmonic function.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I was looking again at the same answer. You are absolutely right! Trusting this answer I started to have a lot of strange consequences :-))).

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that...

Comment: What about this answer. I am not an expert of stack exchange. We leave it wrong? Maybe it is more useful to leave it wrong as far as one then reads the comments.

Comment: It's up to OP. I will delete if he prefers or I can leave it as you say.